# Angular2, how i can pass attributes from parent to child

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a custom component "SuperField"

```html
<div>
    <input name="super" />
    <input name="field" />
</div>
```

is called so:

```html
<super-component [disabled]="true" [superDirective]="control"></super-component>
```

and i want to pass custom & default attribute directives from parent to child without explicit define them and this directives should be removed from the host (in the DOM):

```html
<div>
    <input name="super" [disabled]="true" [superDirective]="control" />
    <input name="field" [disabled]="true" [superDirective]="control" />
</div>
```

so i can pass every ng2 attribute directive without define them in the ts-file, like:

```js
@Input() disabled: boolean;
@Input() superDirective: any;
```

Can i do this? And if yes, how?

Comment: What do you mean by "without explicit define"?

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to figure out that why you want to do this against Angular's basic feature to keep components independent. By doing this it would be tightly coupled.

Defile a service and keep value objects for your both the directives. Set both of these in parent class and later access it from the child class.

```
valObjCls
{
disabled:boolean;
superDirective:any;
}

ParentClass{

constructor(VO:valObjCls){}
VO.disabled = false;
VO.superDirective = 'parentControl';
}

ChildClass{
constructor(VO:valObjCls)
console.log(VO.disabled);
console.log(VO.superDirective);
}
```